# How can I react to URL hash change with Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, url, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

How can I react to just the URL's hash changing with Iron Router?

I've reimplemented the `action` method in a custom [route controller](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-controllers), in order to control page rendering, however this hook doesn't get invoked if only the URL's hash changes (f.ex. due to the user clicking a link with `href="#about"`). The relevant part of my controller looks like this:

```
@UserController = RouteController.extend({
  action: ->
    tabName = @params.hash
    @state.set("activeTab", tabName)
    @render("user")
})
```

So, basically I need the `action` method to get called whenever the URL hash changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to rerun the route handler when the hash changes, it just doesn't happen by default. In order to make this happen, call `getParams()` on the controller instead of just accessing `params`:

```
@UserController = RouteController.extend({
  action: ->
    tabName = @getParams().hash
    @state.set("activeTab", tabName)
    @render("user")
})
```

`getParams` is a reactive computation that depends on the hash, so since the `action` method of the controller is itself reactive, it will get re-run upon hash change.

Comment: @MichelFloyd It is in the [Iron Router Guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/), but not very easy to discover.

Answer (score 1):

afaik iron-router will not react to a hash change. Two suggestions:

1. Use `window.addEventListener()` to catch the hash change
2. Implement events on the tabs themselves

Option (1) has the advantage that it will work if someone shares a link.

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange",function({
  console.log(document.location);
});
```

Comment: 1) would be my choice here. Could you provide working code for it?

Comment: How would you integrate this with Iron Router though? I.e., how do I make Iron Router re-render due to the new hash value.

Comment: I found out that there is actually support for reacting to hash change, see my answer.